# Triggers in Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, triggers, liquibase

I am using postgresql and I two tables customer (id , name, address, city) and update_customer(id, time). When ever I insert a new value in customer table I want to store that id and time in update_customer table. But I am currently getting an exception and I dont have an idea about what went wrong.

code:

```
<changeSet author="newUser" id="03">
        <sql>
        CREATE TRIGGER customer_trigger
        AFTER INSERT ON customer
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE  customer_update();

        CREATE FUNCTION customer_update() RETURNS trigger AS $example_table$
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO update_customer(id,time) VALUES (NEW.id , current_timestamp);
        RETURN NEW;
        END;
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
```

error

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/trigger.xml::03::newUser:
```

Comment: That SQL syntax is invalid for Postgres. See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) for the correct syntax and [examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name .. I have updated but no use . I am new to this tech so I am not sure whats wrong here .

Comment: Well, that's _still_ invalid. Where in the manual did you find that code?

Comment: i pasted the old code again ...sorry ..I have updated it now

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Using 'createProcedure' tag did the trick for me, I dont why while using 'sql' tag Liquibase kept on throwing errors saying something is wrong near Insert.